# compressing a folder tgz , encode to base64 and send over the fly

Tags: linux, tar, netcat

I am trying to compress a folder, encode to base64 and send it over the fly , but I am getting a error

> tar: Cowardly refusing to create an empty archive

```
tar -czf Pictures | base64 | nc remote_host 443  

nc -lvp 443 | base64 -d > secret.tgz # remote host
```

how can I compres my folder and send it over the fly correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command is giving an error of "empty" archive because your are not passing it anything to tar for compressing.

When using `-f` what comes after should be the name of the archive to create and only then archives to compress (on your case, a directory).

For sending it to stdout to feed it to pipe, you should use the dummy option/shortcut "-"

As in:

```
tar -czf - Pictures | base64 | nc remote_host 443
```

As also @muru correctly points out, tar output to stdout by default, so another option if taking out the "-f".

```
tar -cz Pictures | base64 | nc remote_host 443
```

`nc` also in theory is also well capable of handling binary files when not sending them to the console, you can do without the extra step of base64 enconding and decoding. I certainly did it thousands of times without using base64.

I would also prefer using the `nc` without -v for scripting in the remote side as in:

```
tar -czf - Pictures | nc remote_host 443  
nc -lp 443 > secret.tgz # remote host
```

Comment: The `f -` is redundant; `tar` outputs to stdin by default if no output file is specified (so `tar cz Pictures | ...`)

Comment: @muru I know you mean stdout, thanks for pointing it out, and I prefer the notation of having - before arguments.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro ah, yes, typo.